# Why "wir beiden" instead of "wir beide"?

Tags: adjective-ending

Ich habe [ein Beispiel im Internet](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html) gesehen.

> Wir beiden sind da, aber wo bleiben die anderen?

Ich kann das zweite Beispiel (z. B. *die anderen*) verstehen, aber ich habe keine Idee, warum das erste Beispiel richtig ist. Meiner Meinung nach soll das "Wir beide sind da" und nicht "Wir beiden sind da" sein. Warum *wir beiden* hier?

Comment: Weil nicht alles, was in Internet steht, stimmt? IMHO hast Du recht mit "wir beide".

Comment: It is simply wrong (may be used regionally or in some dialects nevertheless), "wir beide" is correct.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Ich war recht :)

Comment: For those who might raise the same question, I found the example here => http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html

Comment: How about a question about “recht" and “richtig" :)

Comment: that is certainly a valid question.

Comment: @user3787757: »Ich war recht« is wrong. In German you ARE not right, you HAVE right. Correct is: »Ich hatte recht«

Comment: Ja I thought so :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dieser Satz ist nicht falsch.
Es ist eine seltenere Variante. Bedenkt, dass man häufig **ihr beiden** sagt.

Ein Zitat von Heinrich Heine:

> *Wahrhaftig, wir beiden bilden ein kurioses Paar, die Liebste ist schwach auf den Beinen, der Liebhaber lahm sogar*

Der Duden

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beide

sagt Folgendes:

> • wir beide, *seltener* wir beiden
>
> • ihr beiden, *auch* ihr beide
>
> • wir, ihr beiden jungen Leute

**Also:**

Beide Versionen sind korrekt, wenn auch nicht gleichermaßen gebräuchlich. Für "wir" und "sie" verwendet man häufiger die Form ohne "n". Für "ihr" häufiger mit "n". Warum das so ist? Das könnte die nächste Frage auf German.SE sein.

Comment: Im täglichen Leben ist die Form `wir beiden` eigentlich nicht anzutreffen. Man wird also sehr wahrscheinlich "anecken" damit.

Comment: @frlan: *Immer werden wir so bleiben jung und frei und schön.
**Wir beiden** stehen auf der guten Seite Jahr für Jahr* - Juli Songtext aus "Wir beide" (gesungen oder gesporchen hört man das 'n' vermutlich nicht so sehr).

Comment: Songtexte von Juli würde ich in meinem Sozialisierungsumfeld eher als unüblich bezeichnen ;). Aber im Ernst: Selbst dort halten sie es eher inkonsequent, müsste der Titel dann doch `Wir beiden` heißen. Aber muss zugeben, man hört es dort recht gut (gerade mal reingehört)

Comment: Jawohl. Wie oben hinreichend belegt, ist "wir beiden" richtiges Deutsch. Ich verwende es oft, denn es erlaubt feinste Unterscheidungen: "Fischer sind wir beiden nicht (aber Jaeger)"/"Fischer sind wir beide nicht (aber angeln koennen wir)". Im zweiten Fall ist die Gemeinsamkeit viel zentraler. Anders gesagt: "Wir beiden" ist vorrangig ein "wir", "wir beide" hauptsaechlich ein "beide".

Comment: Dass eine semantische Unterscheidung zwischen den Formen besteht wusste ich nicht @Ludi. Beruht das auf irgendeiner grammatischen Regel? Kann hier ein anderer Muttersprachler diesen Unterscheid bestätigen? (Bin bloss neugierig).

Comment: @seesharper Ich bin leider kein Grammatikwunder und habe mich auf mein Sprachgefühl verlassen. Dieses besagt: die Nebenform "wir beiden" erlaubt es "both of us" und "the two of us" schriftlich zu unterscheiden, denn "wir beiden" bedeutet nur "the two of us". Ich wollte damit nicht sagen "wir beide" dürfe nicht auch "wir beiden" bedeuten.

Comment: @Ludi meinst du die andere Betonung, die jeweils zu Bedeutungsnuancen führt? Also "*wir* beiden" und "wir *beide*" sozusagen?

Comment: @BarthZalewski Ja. Nach meinem Verständnis, kann man mündlich durch diese Betonung differenzieren. Da man dass schriftlich meist nicht kann, greift man zu "wir beiden", welches stets "the two of us" bedeutet.

Answer (score -1):

Dieser Satz ist falsch: »Wir *beiden* sind da, aber wo bleiben die anderen?«

Richtig ist:

> Wir *beide* sind da, aber wo bleiben die anderen?

(»beide« ohne n)